# SQL Server 2008 can't repair consistency

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a problem with a SQL Server 2008 database.

Launching

```
DBCC CHECKDB
```

I get this error:

> *SQL Server detected a logical consistency-based I/O error: incorrect
>   checksum (expected: 0xd2e00940; actual: 0x925ef494). It occurred
>   during a read of page (1:15215) in database ID 22 at offset
>   0x000000076de000 in file 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\file.mdf'. 
>   Additional messages in the SQL Server error log or system event log
>   may provide more detail. This is a severe error condition that
>   threatens database integrity and must be corrected immediately.
>   Complete a full database consistency check (DBCC CHECKDB). This error
>   can be caused by many factors; for more information, see SQL Server
>   Books Online.*

I found the table causing the problem:

```
DBCC CHECKTABLE
```

> *Msg 824, Level 24, State 2, Line 8
>
>   SQL Server detected a logical
>   consistency-based I/O error: incorrect checksum (expected: 0xd2e00940;
>   actual: 0x925ef494). It occurred during a read of page (1:15215) in
>   database ID 22 at offset 0x000000076de000 in file 'C:\Program
>   Files\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\file.mdf'. 
>   Additional messages in the SQL Server error log or system event log
>   may provide more detail. This is a severe error condition that
>   threatens database integrity and must be corrected immediately.*
>
> *Complete a full database consistency check (DBCC CHECKDB). This error
>   can be caused by many factors; for more information, see SQL Server
>   Books Online.*

So I tried with the repair operations:

```
DBCC CHECKTABLE (table_name, REPAIR_ALLOW_DATA_LOSS)
```

but I get the same error:

> *Msg 824, Level 24, State 2, Line 8
>
>   SQL Server detected a logical
>   consistency-based I/O error: incorrect checksum (expected: 0xd2e00940;
>   actual: 0x925ef494). It occurred during a read of page (1:15215) in
>   database ID 22 at offset 0x000000076de000 in file 'C:\Program
>   Files\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\file.mdf'. 
>   Additional messages in the SQL Server error log or system event log
>   may provide more detail. This is a severe error condition that
>   threatens database integrity and must be corrected immediately.*
>
> *Complete a full database consistency check (DBCC CHECKDB). This error
>   can be caused by many factors; for more information, see SQL Server
>   Books Online.*

I've also tried setting the DB in SINGLE_USER mode, but with no result.

I am not able to delete nor truncate the table. As I always get the same error.

The table does not have any constraints. It has one PK and one Index, but I can't drop any of them.

Comment: I've already tried the repair WITH REPAIR_ALLOW_DATA_LOSS, but it does not work and gives me back an error message. I don't have a good backup to be used for the entire DB. Is it possible to restore only the broken table from a simple backup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find a fast solution, so I recovered from a backup.
I created a DB restoring an old backup.
Then I updated the datas in the new DB importing them from the broken DB, bypassing the broken tables.
Finally I replaced the broken DB with the new one.
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 4):

You need to restore the page from a full backup, then applying the logs forward to current or you need to do a full restore.

I'd also run chkdsk as it appears you might be having a disk problem as the same page is reporting problems when attempting to repair it.  Also run any disk management tools and see if they report problems with the disk.

Comment: Being that you are in simple recovery a full restore is your only option. Had you been in full recovery and taking transaction log backups you could have restored just the page instead of the entire database.  This is one of the known limitations of the simple recovery model.