# SQL Server consistency I/O base error

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have received this error while performing queries on a database (SQL Server 2012)

> msg 824, level 24, state 2, line 1 sql server detected a logical consistency-based i/o error. Incorrect page ID (expected page ID  : 88:89436 ; real page ID : 0:0)  It occurred during a read of page (88:89436) in database ID 49 at offset 0x0000002bab8000 in file 'C:\BackupData\Sales\S0086.NDF'.

Can anyone tell me how to fix this issue?

Comment: Check you disk subsystem as this indicates a problem with disk subsystem.

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/36505/sql-server-2008-cant-repair-consistency